# Sample Multiple Points from Raster Layer Python QGIS 3.26.1

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sampling, query-layer

I have the coordinates for 30000 locations I would like to to sample from raster layers. These locations are not located next to one another. This is currently done with an external python script and takes hours to loop through the array of coordinates, creating a QgsPointXY object and then sampling the raster layer at that single location.

```
values = [0.0] * len(x_coords)
for i in range(len(x_coords)):
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(path)
    values[i] = layer.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(x_coord[i], y_coord[i]), 1)[0]
```

Is there a way to sample multiple points from a raster layer in QGIS 3.26.1 with python?

If this is possible, is it faster than iterating through each point separately?

I have looked through the QGIS Python API documentation for QGIS and cannot find anything

Comment: Do the points already exist? And what exactly do you mean by "sample points"?

Comment: @Erik At present I have the x and y coordinates, then create the QgsPointXY right before I sample it.

Comment: And "sampling" is defined as "attaching raster values to points" for you?

Comment: @Erik I would like to obtain the value of the raster layer at that point. The QGIS Python API do this for a single location and specific band with the sample() method and use the language "sample"

Comment: Have you had a look at the native `rastersampling` tool?

Comment: You are aware that you can load text files with x,y coordinates in QGIS natively as a vector layer?

Comment: @JochenSchwarze Yes. Once I get a vector layer how would I sample a value from a raster file for each feature of the vector layer using the QGIS Python API? I want to use Python rather than using the QGIS interface.

Comment: @Erik I have used it with the QGIS interface previously, however I have never used it with an external python script. I looked in the QGIS Python API documentation and I could not find anything about it. I could not see anything online about using it with python either. Do you know how to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short answer:***

**Yes**, **Yes** (way faster), https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#sample-raster-values

***Long answer:***

I would also prefer using the algorithm ('Sample raster values') from the processing toolbox, but note well that **all processing algorithms can be executed from the python console**. Accessing the processing toolbox gives you useful information as well:

1. Mouseover the algorithm reveals the algorithm ID, here: `native:rastersampling`

[image]

2. Execute the algorithm from the gui:

[image]

3. Have a look at the Log:

[image]

**Note** first the execution time, 0.70sec. for 30k points (way faster than a couple hours)

**Note** also the `Input parameters` and the `Results`, both python dictionaries.

With this informations gathered, the python code is almost self-explanatory:

```
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_points')[0]
raster_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_raster')[0]

params = {'COLUMN_PREFIX':'SAMPLE_',
'INPUT' : point_lyr,
'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
'RASTERCOPY' : raster_lyr}

result = processing.run('native:rastersampling', params)

result_lyr = result['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result_lyr)
```

Results in

[image]

... and welcome to GIS.SE btw!